# How to add Image in jspdf?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have tried this code for add a image,but here Image has been not adding with pdf.

```
  function RunCode() {
       var imgData = 'data:pubali.jpg/jpeg;';
       var doc = new jsPDF();
       doc.setFontSize(10);
       doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
       doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
       doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
       doc.output('datauri');
     }
```

How can I add image with jspdf.

Comment: *imgdData* shuld string containing *base64* encoded *jpg/jpeg* image file

Answer (score 3):

1. You Will make your image into a Data url.
2. Go to this link http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php for convert your image into a url.
3. Then follow this link http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/ add your data url like this.

Answer (score 0):

problem is you are not  find out datauri,

```
 [1] : [http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php]
```

click this link upload your image.find out your datauri.