# How to export report as PDF/CSV in ChartNew.js

Tags: javascript, export-to-csv, chart.js, chartnew.js

I am using ChartNew.js for Horizontal Stacked bar report. I am not sure how to export chart report to **PDF and CSV format with ChartNew.js?**

I tried but could not find any solution. Any help with sample code would highly appreciated.

Comment: pdf and csv are two different formats.  Pick one and focus on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure how to export chart report to PDF and CSV format with
> ChartNew.js?

Since you've put CSV, I presume you mean the data and not the chart.

For CSV, you can easily generate the file based on https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180 with mostly string concatenation and wrapping. You could also do the same thing on the client side using Data URIs (see [How to create a file in memory for user to download, but not through server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server))

For PDF, it might be easier to use a library. For .NET, [Best Server-side .NET PDF editing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204860/best-server-side-net-pdf-editing-library) should give you a good solution. There is also a JAVA version of it.

---

If you are looking to export the chart as well, CSV does not support this.

For PDF, you could export your canvas to a data URI (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)
and use a client side library like jspdf (see [How to add Image in jspdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007854/how-to-add-image-in-jspdf) for an example) or do the same thing on the server using iText / iTextSharp (see [Inputting image data to PDF with iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223769/inputting-image-data-to-pdf-with-itext))

Comment: Awesome!! This is exactly I was looking for. Thank you for the help :)